# interpolating an arbitrary 2D slice through a 3D deformed hexahedral mesh

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, mesh

**Overview** I'm working on a Python project involving numerical analysis and visualization, specifically using numpy and scipy. I need to project scalar values from a 3D field onto a slightly curved 3D surface, but I'm encountering challenges due to the unique characteristics of my dataset.

My dataset consists of a scalar field defined over a 3D volume of approximately 200 x 200 x 100 points. Each point is associated with x, y, and z coordinates, represented by four numpy 3D arrays. Ideally, I could use scipy's griddata for a regular grid, but my data have irregularities and large variations in the grid spacing, which complicates the use of both regular Radial Basis Function (RBF) interpolation and griddata.

Specific Challenges:

- *Irregular-Regular Grid*: The x, y, and z coordinates are not evenly spaced, exhibiting skewed deformations that result in non-uniform dx, dy, and dz values across the mesh. However, it is technically a rectilinear-ish hexahedral mesh. dx_i, dy_i, and dz_i values are no more than 30% different than neighboring divisions, and for much of the nodes values less than 10% are typical. All hexahedra are convex. Most hexahedra are deformed at least a little bit.
- *Variable Hexahedra Dimensions*: The dimensions of hexahedra vary significantly across the mesh. For example, dimensions near the center faces of the overall modeled volume might be 30m x 100,000m x 30m, whereas corners are more uniform at 100,000m x 100,000m x 100,000m. This variation makes the use of scipy's RBF interpolator or related methods challenging due to the absence of a single applicable length-scale.
- *Projection onto a Curved Surface*: The ultimate goal is to project a 2D-like slice through this 3D volume and interpolate the scalar values onto a surface representing the slice. This surface is mostly flat but has a number of limited deformations in the x-y plane.

Since my stack here is 100% python and largely uses scipy and numpy, the idea solution would use toolkits consistent with these packages. I've tried:

1. Regridding depth-wise onto a common, cartesian coordinate-aligned x-y-z grid using griddata. This works, but takes DAYS on my m1 macbook. Does not work when applied to the mesh I get an error message indicating the need for unphysically large amounts of memory (>100TB).
2. Using a scipy RBF interpolator and setting nearest neighbors to a smaller amount. Works in domains with more consistent dx,dy, and dz but otherwise results in large NaN regions on the target surface.

Both outcomes are just not suitable in execution time or accuracy to the overall problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this post is off-topic for Stack Overflow since you're only asking for advice and don't have any code. That said... `scipy.interpolate.griddata` works for unstructured data, the `scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator` does not.

Comment: Perhaps I should rewrite my question then. I've tried griddata. It doesn't work for my problem; scipy throws an error saying the memory required would be ridiculous (>100TB!)